# Select2 render multiple time when navigating to previous page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I have a select2 drop down

```
    $('.range-selection').select2({width: 'resolve',
      placeholder: "Select range", prompt: "select"
    });
```

Its working fine but when navigating to a different page and then navigating to same page again the select2 field gets render multiple times.
How to avoid select2 render multiple time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to destroy the select2 field when `turbolinks:before-cache`, This will prevent the multiple select2 in the page

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:before-cache", function() {
 $('.range-selection').select2('destroy');
});
```

Comment: since Rails7 and Turbo we need to use `'turbo:before-cache'`